# What's the probability of drawing all ranks in a standard 52-card deck?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Suppose a player is dealt with 16 cards under a standard 52-card deck, it's easy to find all possible combinations, which is ${52}\choose{16}$.

However, I am struggling on finding all possible combinations that those 16 cards contains all ranks.

And also wondering is there any general formula for finding such combination when cards dealt is more than 13?

Comment: Just off the record: did you ask this on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-probability-of-drawing-all-ranks-in-a-standard-52-card-deck) as well? Exactly the same title there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer works under the convention that for nonnegative integer $m$ and integer $i$ we have: $$i\notin\left\{ 0,\dots,m\right\} \implies\binom{m}{i}=0$$

---

Number the ranks with $1,2,\dots,13$ and let $R:=\left\{ 1,2,\dots,13\right\} $.

Define the random set $\hat{R}\subseteq R$ by stating that $r\in\hat{R}$
if and only if a card with rank $r$ is dealt.

Then to be found is: $$P\left(\hat{R}=R\right)$$

---

By means of inclusion/exclusion we find the (*nice*) general expression:$$P\left(\hat{R}=R\right)=P\left(\hat{R}\subseteq R\right)-P\left(\bigcup_{r\in R}\left\{ \hat{R}\subseteq R-\left\{ r\right\} \right\} \right)=$$$$\sum_{T\subseteq R}P\left(\hat{R}\subseteq T\right)\left(-1\right)^{\left|R\right|-\left|T\right|}\tag1$$

In the knowledge that $R$ has cardinality $13$ we find the (a bit less general) expression:$$P\left(\hat{R}=R\right)=\sum_{T\subseteq R}P\left(\hat{R}\subseteq T\right)\left(-1\right)^{13-\left|T\right|}\tag2$$

If $n$ cards are dealt (so in your question $n=16$) then: $$P\left(\hat{R}\subseteq T\right)=\binom{52}{n}^{-1}\binom{4\left|T\right|}{n}$$

Observe that $P\left(\hat{R}\subseteq T\right)$ only depends
on the cardinality of $T$ so that finally we can refine $(2)$ by: $$P\left(\hat{R}=R\right)=\binom{52}{n}^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{13}\binom{13}{k}\binom{4k}{n}\left(-1\right)^{13-k}\tag3$$

Comment: Wondering what's the definition of the set T?

Comment: $T$ is not a specific set (so does not need a definition) but serves as index for the summation ranging over all subsets of $R$. If e.g. we use an expression like $\sum_{i=1}^5f (i) $ then similarly a definition of $i$ makes no sense. We just let $i$ take the values $1,2,3,4,5$. Likewise we let $T $ take all subsets of $R $ as value.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the answer, it does work.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I repaired a typo. Index $k$ in last expression should start at $0$ (not at $1$).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $13$ (distinguishable) bins, each with max capacity of $4$ balls.

When, upon shuffling the deck of cards, you start and distribute one by one
that is the same as **launching** a sequence of balls into the bins.

You can then proceed as indicated in many posts on this version of the problem, 
for example [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408523).